# Managing configuration files on a server in solaris environment and frequently changes by multiple users

Tags: solaris, config

I have an application running on a solaris machine with configuration modifications and deletions of configuration handled by multiple persons in the team....I would like to streamline this process to ensure no loss of configuration and make it easier to identify when/where the changes are done and by whom and retreive the configuration files as necessary.

I looked at svn and other repositories but they all seem to work with a repository stored on some machine and all the chnages have to be made then and there....

I am hoping to find a solution where a service would be running on solaris in teh background and monitors the changes and automatically creates the necessary versioning.

Am I asking for something that doesn't exist? or are they better approaches to solving this issue?

Thank you.....

Answer (score 0):

A couple thoughts.  If you mean system configuration then you can use SMF (Service Management Facility).  This provides a service for managing the configuration, inter dependencies, and the running of services.  Tracking of changes is easy but I'm not so sure if versioning would be easy to manage.

The next to last paragraph makes me think you want to allow the user to make ad hoc changes and have some daemon monitor and store those.  That could probably be done with FAM and maybe use of ZFS versioning but that seems like overkill.

As far as a better approach.  I would tend to use ZFS snapshots or a like mechanism to checkpoint my configuration.  And then I would use SMF to manage my configuration.  Maintaining versions of the configuration of individual subsystems doesn't quite do it for me.  It is the configuration of the whole box that is interesting.